# Advices about website's architecture and how to deal with docker containers

Tags: docker, web, architecture, frontend, backend

I want to start working on a project but I don't know if it's possible (I guess so), I want to implement 3 versions of backend and frontend each in a different language like in the picture below. I want to dockerize each of the "version". 
So far so good.

[Basic Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1y56.png)

I wonder what is the best solution ; is it to run all containers and map each container on different port and switch between them when clicking on a button like "switch to angular" ?

Or a solution, that everytime I clicked on a button like "switch to react", then it start the container that runs react app and stop the old one. I guess this one is more efficient because there is only two containers running (backend and frontend) but I'm not sure if it's possible to start a container from just clicking on a button.

Second question is how I deal with X containers to choose which one to run ?

Where I could deploy that kind of appication ? Any PaaS or anything else to advice ?

If you have any other advices to provide, I'll take them with pleasure

Note : The project have absolutley 0 interest, it's only training and discover technologies.

Answer (score 0):

So you might want to look into Kubernetes.  Kubernetes is a container orchestration service that allows you to very seamlessly connect to other running containers. So for instance you could have 6 containers running, one for each of your services, and then have the ability to switch between containers via env variables.  For example if you were running in the react container and you wanted to use the Go BE you could set `BE_CONTAINER=GO`.  Then on your front end you would read in the env var and connect to that running server.

Alternatively you could run 9 front ends and only the 3 backends. Each container only related to a singular backend.  This is obviously less ideal, but an option.

Kubernetes in general is a pretty advanced topic when you are just starting out. You have to start looking at your project as "what is the big picture" and "how easy can it be to scale".  I like Kubernetes because I do feel like this could be a good choice for you, but it is not the only choice.  You can 100% stick to just docker.  But for the application you are describing, personally, I would look into using Kubernetes.